# Mobile Number Validation in Ionic Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a Cordova Ionic App. I have tried below code. The directive is working fine in ios but not in Android. It is allowing user to enter special character. Can anyone please tell how I can resolve this.

**Register.html**

```
                    <label class="item item-input"> <span><i
                            class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i></span> <input type="number"
                        ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/" placeholder="Mobile" only-num 
                        ng-model="register.mobile_number" name="mobile" ng-minlength="10"
                        ng-maxlength="10" required>
                    </label>
```

**app.js**

```
            app.directive('onlyNum', function() {
                return function(scope, element, attrs) {

                    var keyCode = [8,9,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,110];
                    element.bind("keydown", function(event) {
                        console.log($.inArray(event.which,keyCode));
                        if($.inArray(event.which,keyCode) == -1) {
                            scope.$apply(function(){
                                scope.$eval(attrs.onlyNum);
                                event.preventDefault();
                            });
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }

                    });
                };
            });
```

I have tried below directive as well :

**Register.html**

```
                    <label class="item item-input"> <span><i
                            class="icon ion-ios-telephone-outline"></i></span> <input type="number"
                        ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/" placeholder="Mobile" allow-pattern="\d"
                        ng-model="register.mobile_number" name="mobile" ng-minlength="10"
                        ng-maxlength="10" required>
                    </label>
```

**app.js**

```
    app.directive('allowPattern', [allowPatternDirective]);

            function allowPatternDirective() {
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
                        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                            // I handle key events
                            element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                                var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode; // I safely get the keyCode pressed from the event.
                                var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode); // I determine the char from the keyCode.

                                // If the keyCode char does not match the allowed Regex Pattern, then don't allow the input into the field.
                                if (!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    return false;
                                }

                            });
                        };
                    }
                };
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this directive it will allow only numbers

```
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == undefined)
                    return '';
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

and please include this directive in your input filed

```
<input type="text" numbers-only>
```

this works fine for me

Comment: please include numbers-only  as directive in input field this will work

Comment: <input type="text" numbers-only>

Comment: add one thing give input type as tel it will show keyboard consist of only numbers.

Comment: <input type="tel" numbers-only>